# c# Convert double to string issue

Tags: c#, string, double, converters

I need your help on converting double to string

Here is my example double value

```
-981676354.3150035

4.920001983642578
```

I Want to convert that numbers

but If I use ToStinrg function like this

```
double value = -981676354.3150035;
var str = value.ToString("R");
```

It return **-981676354.31500351** by adding 1 to the end

or

return **-981676354.315004** by rounds up

I entirely want to convert double value itself to a string
(ex -981676354.3150035 => -981676354.3150035)

Please Help!

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: I can't reproduce. It does not add a 1 at the end for me.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/u6bvT7

Comment: @TheGeneral Change the compiler to .NET 4.7.2 or Roslyn.

Comment: Hmm, can different results be produced depending on the execution environment?

With the exact same code, my computer is returning a result with end of 1

Comment: do you want the amount of decimals to be fixed in the string representation of the double?

Comment: And to maden the madness https://dotnetfiddle.net/QQDlDa

Comment: @MongZhu Unfortunately, the number of decimal places is flexible.

Comment: Use `decimal` if you want confidence in the result.

Comment: @mjwills i wonder if this touches on the huge flamewar post the other week about the bug with literals ect. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4074

Comment: It could be the same issue @TheGeneral. Nonetheless - `double` is the wrong data type here.